# Numpy functions return array class instance when called on subclass of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Some numpy functions (logically) return scalars:

```
>>> my_arr = np.ndarray(shape=(1,))
>>> type(np.max(my_arr))
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

but only when called with an ndarray, rather than a subclass:

```
>>> class CustomArray(np.ndarray):
...     pass
>>> my_arr = CustomArray(shape=(1,))
>>> type(np.max(my_arr))
<class '__main__.CustomArray'>
```

Why is this? I'd expect either both to return a scalar (of type `<type 'numpy.float64'>`, or the former to return a `np.ndarray` instance and the latter a `CustomArray` instance. But instead, I get a combination of these two behaviours. Can I change this behaviour through changing my own class?

I don't see anything that would explain this on the doc page discussing subclassing ndarray (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/user/basics.subclassing.html).

(Running Python 2.7.10, numpy 1.9.2, in case it matters.)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `max()` is not overloaded in `CustomArray`. If you try it, `my_array.max()` returns an object of CustomArray instead of scalar.

```
my_array = CustomArray(shape=(1,))
print my_array.max()
>> CustomArray(9.223372036854776e+18)
```

`np.max` internally calls `np.amax`, which ends up calling `np.maximum.reduce`. This is the standard `reduce` of map-reduce and returns a base-object returned by max. Hence, the type returned by `np.max` is in fact the type returned by `max()` method called on your object. You can override it as:

```
class CustomArray(np.ndarray):
   def max(self, axis, out):
      return np.ndarray(self.shape, buffer=self).max(axis, out)

type(np.max(my_arr))
>> numpy.float64
```

The trick is to upcast self as an `np.ndarray` and find max using it.

Comment: I'm guessing then that I have to change pretty much every method that `ndarray` instances get? (I was just using `max` as an example.)

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question of why the instance of a subclass behaves differently from an instance of ndarray, if the subclass doesn't actually alter any behaviour.

Comment: Yes, you probably have to update every relevant method, if you want the right return type. The class body does not update anything, but the default overrides of max() (and additional methods like sum()) are different from base np.ndarray.

Comment: Why are they different though? Is there an explicit check in `ndarray.max` to check that `self` is actually an instance of `ndarray` and not a subclass or something?

Comment: Look at the code for `np.matrix` or `masked` to see how they handle this.

Comment: The `matrix` subclass passes many of its methods through `np.matrix._collapse` which returns `self[0, 0]` in 'scalar' situations.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this, solved it for all aggregation/reduction operations in NumPy by implementing a custom [`__array_wrap__`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs-and-other-functions):

```py
import numpy as np

class CustomArray(np.ndarray):
    def __array_wrap__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        if obj.shape == ():
            return obj[()]
        else:
            return super().__array_wrap__(obj, **kwargs)
```

Example return types for various operations:

```py
>>> a = CustomArray(shape=(3,))
>>> type(np.max(a))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type(np.median(a))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type(np.exp(a))
<class '__main__.CustomArray'>
>>>
```